# Remove Mood Lighting on 1994 Ford Econoline E150 Magnum van

Tags: electrical, ford, van

I will be removing the Mood Lighting . Do I need to disconnect the battery for that? It is possible I might still use some of it and redirect it to my solar energy. I would appreciate any help I can get, as this is my first time converting a van.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, what do you mean by mood lighting? How are you looking to use solar energy?

Answer (score 0):

Car batteries have very high amperage, so i would highly suggest you disconnect your battery before doing maintenance or installation on your vehicule. Regarding the energy, you need to check the voltage of the truck battery and the voltage of your solar powering system, you might need to buy a dc to dc converter to have the right voltage powering the lighting. Just be careful with those batteries, you will not be electrocuted but you can get burned by the current.